# Сочетаются ли глаголы разного вида?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, редактура

…к Этайн подлетела феечка. Замерла перед самым лицом, залопотала встревоженно:

— Беги, беги, Этайн! Беги! Это же волки!

— О чем это она? — изумленная Этайн протянула открытую ладонь.

***Несносная малявка уселась, скрестив ножки и сложив перламутровые крылышки, и то прижимала ручонки к сердцу, то возводила их к небесам.***

Мидир нахмурился. Даже его подданные не ожидают ничего хорошего для этой женщины!

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, построже, можно ли так сформулировать выделенное предложение. Мне кажется, как-то корявенько: уселась… и то прижимала… то возводила... Или это моя мнительность?

Answer (score 2):

Сочетаются глаголы разного вида: ***уселась*** обозначает законченное действие,   а ***то прижимала, то возводила*** ― длительное (незавершенное) действие  прошлом.

Пример: Она **уселась** и нетерпеливо **грызла** косу всё время, пока мы разговаривали. [Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана (1938-1944)]